# Librería FPDF de PHP ¿Cómo ajustar texto en una celda?

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

buen día, ¿alguien puede orientarme en cómo ajustar texto en una celda?
La cabecera de mi tabla es el siguiente:

```
/*muy bien, ya sabemos que arriba va el header y footer de la página,
iré al grano
*/

//Mi tabla contiene la siguiente cabecera:
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 11);
//aquí ya no hay salto de línea, por lo tanto las celdas van a continuar
$pdf->Cell(10, 8, 'No', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(60, 8, 'Producto', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(30, 8, 'Factor', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(35, 8, 'Contenido', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(35, 8, 'P. Unit', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(35, 8, 'Cantidad', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(50, 8, 'Subtotal', 1, 1, 'C', 0);

//Mi tabla contiene las siguientes celdas:
//Ok, es hora de darle color a las celdas y color a las líneas
$pdf->SetFillColor(233, 229, 235); // color de fondo rgba
$pdf->SetDrawColor(61, 61, 61); // color de la linea

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12); //tipo de letra para las celdas
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {    
    $pdf->Cell(10, 8, $i, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(60, 8, 'Lapicero Pin Point Negro Fino', 1, 0, 'C', 0); 
    $pdf->Cell(30, 8, 'Unidad', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, 'Caja de lapiceros pin point', 1, 0, 'C', 0);     // Este texto se sale de su celda, ¿cómo hago para que se ajuste?
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, '32.50', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, '6', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(50, 8, '630.00', 1, 1, 'C', 0);
}


$pdf->Output();
```

Adjunto una imagen remarcando de rojo los textos que sobresalen de su respectiva celda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo ajustar el texto?
De antemano agradezco hayan leído hasta aquí.

Comment: Reduce el ancho de otras celdas e incrementa la de contenido.

Answer (score 4):

También puedes probar a utilizar $pdf->MultiCell igual se adapta más a lo que buscas. Más información [aquí](http://www.fpdf.org/)